# 15.04 I get terrible screen tearing on the desktop with intel graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.04

So I gave 15.04 a try but the screen tearing on the desktop (scrolling in web browsers, moving windows) is as terrible as in every version of ubuntu I've ever tried, and it always ends with me giving up on trying to actually use the system. Enabling VSync under OpenGL in CompizConfig Settings Manager doesn't make any difference. So, before nuking this OS for the 100th time, I have to ask if there's something I'm missing here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I think it is a duplicate of:
[Screen tearing in Ubuntu with Nvidia/Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics/)

But anyway. 
Try adding a line:
`Option "TearFree" "true"` in the `Device` section, in the following file: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

For more options just `man intel`.

I just fixed my own setup yesterday this way. I have found useful info at the arch linux page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Installation